# Conditional comment -- loads in all browsers; should only load in IE 8 and below

Tags: html5-video, conditional-comments

This is loading in all browsers, when I only want it to load in IE 8 and below.  Any thoughts as to why?  Do I have a typo that my code-fatigued eyes are missing?

```
<![if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="HTTP://dev.brandgnumedia.com/html5video/jplayer/js/ieplayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]>
```

FYI:  If I don't use the lte operator, and just do `<![if IE]>` it works fine.  It's an HTML5 video player with flash fallback, and I'd really like it to work that way in IE 9 and keep working when IE 10 comes out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should form it like this

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    what-to-do
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I did try that.  No browser loads the script.  I hate using these things anyway.

Comment: Actually, you were correct.  That is the proper construction for IE.

The way I originally formed it works in other browsers, so now I'm getting the right file everywhere.  Thanks.